# Hyperdimension Neptunia Re;Birth1 Master achievement

Tags: achievements, neptunia-rebirth-1

How do you unlock this achievement? Everywhere I look they just provide the same description as in game.

"You played the game so much, you made Neptune folks proud!"

is it by hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get it for earning all the other achievements.

Comment: Added punctuation to the answer. I take no responsibility for its accuracy or lack thereof.

Comment: To add a bit of support for this answer, it's a platinum trophy on the PS Vita version. All platinum trophies have the same requirement, earn all of the other trophies.